# How to process Kafka partitions separately and in parallel with Spark executors?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

I use Spark 2.1.1.

I read messages from 2 Kafka partitions using Structured Streaming. I am submitting my application to Spark Standalone cluster with one worker and 2 executors (2 cores each).

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class MyClass \
  --master spark://HOST:IP \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  /home/ApplicationSpark.jar
```

I want the functionality such that, the messages from each Kafka partition should be processed by each separate executor independently. But now what is happening is, executors read and .map the partition data separately, but after mapping the unbounded tables which is formed is used commonly and having data from both the partitions.

When I ran the structured query on table, the query has to deal with data from both the partitions (more amount of data).

```sql
select product_id, max(smr.order_time), max(product_price) , min(product_price) 
from OrderRecords
group by WINDOW(order_time, "120 seconds"), product_id
```

where Kafka partition is on `Product_id`

Is there any way to run the same structured query parallel but separately on the data, from the Kafka partition to which the executor is mapped?

Comment: How do you check _"executors read and .map the partition data separately, but after mapping the unbounded tables which is formed is used commonly and having data from both the partitions."_? Do you look at the execution plan? Could you paste it? What else do you use to claim the statement?

Comment: When I print the exe. plan, it is showing **"No Physical plans"**. _What we see when we print the output of count query; it is showing total number of records across partitions.
We do not have requirement to execute query on consolidated data across partitions. What we need is working on smaller dataset independently.
e.g.
Kafka partitions - P1, P2
P1 contains products 1 to 10
P2 contains products 11 to 20
When we run two executor of Spark streaming, we would like to operate on individual dataset of 10 records each._

Answer (score 0):

> But now what is happening is, executors read and .map the partition data separately, but after mapping the unbounded tables which is formed is used commonly and having data from both the partitions. Hence when I ran the structured query on table, the query has to deal with data from both the partitions (more amount of data).

That's the key to understand what and how can be executed without causing shuffle and sending data across partitions (possibly even over the wire).

The definitive answer depends on what your queries are. If they work on groups of records where the groups are spread across multiple topic partitions and hence on two different Spark executors, you'd have to be extra careful with your algorithm/transformation to do the processing on separate partitions (using only what's available in partitions) and aggregating the results only.